# Add to Aspectpath not found MonkeyTalk

Tags: android, monkeytalk

I am trying to work with monkey Talk Android agent but after adding the monkeytalk-agent.jar to Android project  Add to Aspectpath (AspectJ Tools > Add to Aspectpath) is disabled.Why it is so? How can I enable it.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't down vote this question. Googled a lot but not found any solution

Answer (score 2):

It could be because you haven't fully imported the `.jar` file. See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3fAbKysHWs&list=PLBF85C385DD858E41) video for more information on automating Android applications with MonkeyTalk.

Comment: Do you have the explanation how can we import the .jar file??? He did see the video link that you gave, but he faced the problem seeing that video.